# Cannot create lxc container using config file

Tags: linux, lxc, ns-3

I'm following a tutorial [here](https://www.nsnam.org/wiki/HOWTO_Use_Linux_Containers_to_set_up_virtual_networks#HOWTO_Use_Linux_Containers_to_set_up_virtual_networks) on creating linux containers, and I'm running into the following error which I cannot find an answer to:

```
$ sudo lxc-create -f lxc-left.conf -t download -n left -- -d fedora -r 26 -a amd64
lxc-create: left: parse.c: lxc_file_for_each_line_mmap: 100 Permission denied - Failed to open file "lxc-left.conf"
Setting up the GPG keyring
ERROR: Unable to fetch GPG key from keyserver
lxc-create: left: lxccontainer.c: create_run_template: 1625 Failed to create container from template
lxc-create: left: tools/lxc_create.c: main: 331 Failed to create container left
```

The permissions for the file are like so:

```
-rw-rw-rw-. 1 *** domain users  245 Oct  6 13:36 lxc-left.conf
-rw-rw-rw-. 1 *** domain users  248 Oct  6 13:36 lxc-right.conf
```

So I'm not sure why it would give me a permission denied - unless it expects it to be under a certain group.

For GPG keystring error, I know there's an options of `--no-validate` but I want to be able to validate with a gpg key. I am behind a proxy but can ping sites like google, etc.

The source code for the error is [here](https://github.com/lxc/lxc/blob/99858040666b8f281e933db6825902b479a98501/src/lxc/parse.c#L78)

Comment: Does this actually relate to the C programming language which has been tagged or is that a mis-tag?

Comment: Had meant to add the link to the source code where the error is occurring. Added now.

Comment: Resolve your "permission denied" problem first.